# Anyone have a solution for generating server-side tokens for the ESRI JSAPI SDK?

Tags: arcgis-js-api

There are a number of solutions to this:

1. use the build-in dialog provided by esri/IdentityManager (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/identitymanagerbase-amd.html)
2. use a server-side proxy (https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy)
3. use the identity manager initialize() method (https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/identitymanagerbase-amd.html#initialize)

But there what is missing is the ability to hook into the request for a token.  I am working with [ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html) and there is no way to know if the server return a 498/499, and no way to update the url to update the token.

I started hacking around in the API to try to hook into various events with no real promise of success. What seems to be missing:

1. a way to detect when a token is needed
2. a way to update the token

Closes I came up with is listening for "dialog-create" but there is no way to disable the dialog apart from throwing an exception, which disables the layer.

I tried replacing the "_createLoginDialog" method and returning {open: true} as a trick to pause the layers until I had a token ready but since there is no way to update the layer endpoint I did not pursue this hack.  It seems the *only* way this might work is to use the initialize() method on the identity manager.

Does anyone have knowledge of options beyond what I have outlined?

EDIT: The goal is to provide a single-sign-on experience to users of our product.
"User" is already signed in to our application
"User" wishes to access a secure ESRI ArcGIS Server MapServer or FeatureServer services from the ESRI JSAPI
"User" is prompted for user name and password

The desired flow is to acquire a token on the users behalf using a RESTful services in our product and return the appropriate token that will allow the "User" to access the secure services without being prompted.

I do not wish to use a proxy because I do not want all that traffic routed through the proxy.

I do not wish to use initialize() because it is complicated and not clear how that works apart for re-hydrating the credentials.

I do wish for an API that simply allows me to set the token on any layer services that report a 499 (missing token) or 498 (invalid token), but I cannot find any such API.  The solution I am focusing on hinges on being able to update the url of an ArcGISImageServiceLayer instance with a new token.

Comment: I don't understand completely what is the problem you want to solve .. Can you add a sample scenario to the question?

Comment: Updated to include a summary of my situation and why I cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This answer lacks in satisfaction but delivers on my requirements.  I will start with the code (client-side typescript):

```
class TokenProxy {

  private tokenAssuranceHash = {} as Dictionary<Promise<{ token: string, expiration: string }>>;
  private service = new TokenService();
  private timeoutHandle = 0;

  watchLayer(esriLayer: ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer) {
    setInterval(async () => {
      const key = esriLayer._url.path;
      const token = await this.tokenAssurance(key);
      esriLayer._url.query.token = token;
    }, 5000);
  }

  updateRefreshInterval(ticks: number) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandle);
    this.timeoutHandle = setTimeout(() => {
      Object.keys(this.tokenAssuranceHash).forEach(url => {
        this.tokenAssuranceHash[url] = this.service.getMapToken({serviceUrl: url});
      });
      this.updateRefreshInterval(ticks);
    }, ticks);
  }

  async tokenAssurance(url: string) {
    if (!this.tokenAssuranceHash[url]) {
      this.tokenAssuranceHash[url] = this.service.getMapToken({serviceUrl: url});
    }

    try {
      const response = await this.tokenAssuranceHash[url];
      await this.recomputeRefreshInterval();
      return response.token;
    } catch (ex) {
      console.error(ex, "could not acquire token");
      return null;
    }
  }

  async recomputeRefreshInterval() {
    const keys = Object.keys(this.tokenAssuranceHash);
    if (!keys.length) return;
    const values = keys.map(k => this.tokenAssuranceHash[k]);
    const tokens = await Promise.all(values);
    const min = Math.min(...tokens.map(t => new Date(t.expiration).getTime()));
    if (Number.isNaN(min)) return; // error occured, do not update the refresh interval
    const nextRefreshInTicks = min - new Date().getTime();
    this.updateRefreshInterval(0.90 * nextRefreshInTicks);
  }

}
```

And highlight the hack that makes it work:

```
  const key = esriLayer._url.path;
  const token = await this.tokenAssurance(key);
  esriLayer._url.query.token = token;
```

The "_url" is a hidden/private model that I should not be using to update the token but it works.